# Is there a way to append a custom feature in Android fature list inside Android AVD system image?

Tags: android

So, I want to use a 3rd-party app in Android AVD, because AVD has modern Android versions and is more flexible overall, but AVD lacks `android.hardware.opengles.aep` feature.

I know that the app might crash if it can't find required functions, but still, I need to try.
Is it possible to append this feature somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The question became unnecessary because I found out that you can bypass the check by launching a different activity in the target app. In other cases, the only available solution is to patch the app using smali.